# consensual stalker app?

Tags: privacy, gps-tracking

I'm looking for a consensual stalker app on Android. The goal is to make person A able to track person B's location in real time, and read all of their messages (at least messenger and SMS). Bonus features (such as some form of remote control) are welcome, but the features above are mandatory. Since this is intended for fully consensual use, it does not need to be hidden or unremovable.

Answer (score 1):

Try "[Remote SMS, Call, GPS Tracker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobiletrackandroid.remotesmscallgpstracker)" from the Google Play Store.

> Remote SMS, Call, GPS Tracker keeps tracking and monitoring of all your SMS, Calls and Locations data. It’s 100% Free.
>
> ...
>
> - SMS Tracking/Intercept text messages. Read all inbound and outbound messages. Details include name, message, date, phone number, contact name and address.
> - Call Logging/Monitor all inbound, outbound and missed calls. Details include name, call duration, date, phone number, contact name and address.
> - GPS Tracking – Receive GPS locations data from the phone every 60 minutes by default.
> - Retrieve the list of SMS, Calls and Contacts from the remote control.
> - Track your phone in live.

Often phones have 'parental controls' (Kids Mode) in an included APP or the Cellular Provider and manufacturer have a website that allows you to control your phone.

Look out for *hidden* costs in *free* APPs such as privacy concerns or ADs. Near the bottom of the Play Store page are *similar* APPs and there's a search bar at the top to compare features (and permissions) of other APPs.

Comment: Looks good, but is missing Messenger support. A would really like to be able to monitor B's messages from Facebook's Messenter. Are you aware of an alternative that has this?

Comment: You could use [Messenger Kids – Safer Messaging and Video Chat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.talk) in addition to the above suggestion (or another similar APP). I'll keep looking.

Comment: Ideally, B would like the process to be non-intrusive (i.e. B keeps using the stock Messenger app). Of course, A could simply use the web interface using B's password, but that would show B as online and would mark B's conversations as read, so I was hoping for a more tailored app that allows spying along in conversations.

Comment: Also, it seems that the app you suggested only tracks location X times per hour, not in real time. :(

Comment: It looked like you can choose the interval, once a minute is *real* enough (see the map image at the APP's webpage) - unless you want a continuous connection, and poor battery life. If you could edit your question to include which brand of phone you are using it would be helpful. For example Samsung has a website to find your phone, and disable it if stolen. **IF** you want ***continuous*** monitoring then that changes what you are requesting from a 'child monitor' to a 'baby monitor', where a continuous connection is available, that would lack GPS since babies are not particularly mobile.

Comment: An APP such as "[Senior Safety App, GPS Tracker, Fall Alerts & More](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.seniorsafety&hl=en_US)" for monitoring the elderly gives better GPS tracking but while monitoring APP usage lacks ***control*** of messaging in real time. --- Still looking, I haven't forgotten your question. Perhaps another answer twice as good as mine will come and you'll be all set.

Comment: I don't remember it having the option to go down to 1 minute, but I'll install it again, it's been a while since I used this one and they seem to have made some updates since then.

Comment: I deleted my Spyzie answer and replaced it with another APP that seems to clearly be better.

Answer (score 0):

Another full featured, but free (for one device only), APP is [MobileTracker](https://mobile-tracker-free.com/features/):

> - **SMS/MMS** - SMS & MMS tracking, SMS alert
> - Calls - Tracking Call Logs, Call Recording, Blocking calls
> - **GPS** Locations - GPS Position History, **Real-time** tracking
> - Photos - View photos and images
> - Instant messaging - WhatsApp, **Facebook Messenger**, Skype, Hangouts, LINE, Kik, Viber, **Gmail**, Tango, Snapchat, Telegram
> - Remote control - Audio recording, To take a picture, SMS Command, Other Features
> - **Live viewing** - Audio / Video / Screen
> - File Manager - File Explorer and Remote File Download
> - Schedule restriction - Restrict phone use
> - Applications - **Monitoring installed applications**, **Application Blocking**
> - Web sites - **History** of sites visited, **Blocking websites**
> - Calendar - History of events
> - **Contacts** - Track new contacts
> - **Analysis tools** - Statistics, Report PDF / Excel / CVS

Company appears to be located in France. In business since 2014. Very few reviews (too few to judge?) but none were unfavorable.